# Freeradius over TCP

Tags: debian, freeradius

I just installed FreeRadius (Version 3.2.1) on my debian machine and configured the transport protocol of the default testing client to 'tcp'.

```
client localhost {
    ipaddr = 127.0.0.1
    proto = tcp
    secret = testing123
    require_message_authenticator = no
    nas_type     = other    # localhost isn't usually a NAS...
    limit {
        max_connections = 16
        lifetime = 0
        idle_timeout = 30
    }
}
```

No other configuration changes are made.

Testing with radtest shows the following output:

```
radtest -x -P tcp bob hello 127.0.0.1 1812 testing123
radclient: Error opening socket: Failed connecting socket: Connection refused
```

And the server (freeradius -X) remains silent:

```
Listening on auth address * port 1812 bound to server default
Listening on acct address * port 1813 bound to server default
Listening on auth address :: port 1812 bound to server default
Listening on acct address :: port 1813 bound to server default
Listening on auth address 127.0.0.1 port 18120 bound to server inner-tunnel
Listening on proxy address * port 53608
Listening on proxy address :: port 48219
Ready to process requests
```

Any ideas or hints what the problem could be?

Comment: Check with `ss` or `lsof` what ports and addresses it is actually listening on.